# Why AES Produce Different result and Why DES not Produce

Tags: java, encryption, aes, des

I'm trying to change encryption algorithm of existing project. But i have a little bit confusion. When i use "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256" as a parameter, it produce different result but when i use "PBEWithMD5AndDES" as a parameter it produce same result. My functions are :

```
 public static synchronized String encrypt1(final String textToEncrypt, final String pathPublicKey) throws Exception {
    final KeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(DbKeyHandler.getDbKey(pathPublicKey).toCharArray());
    final SecretKey pbeKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
    final AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(pbeKey.getAlgorithm());

    // Create the ciphers
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, paramSpec);

    // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
    final byte[] utf8 = textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF8");

    // Encrypt
    final byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(utf8);

    // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
    return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
}


public static synchronized String encrypt2 (final String textToEncrypt, final String pathPublicKey) throws Exception {
    final KeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(DbKeyHandler.getDbKey(pathPublicKey).toCharArray());
    final SecretKey pbeKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256").generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
    final AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(pbeKey.getAlgorithm());

    // Create the ciphers
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, paramSpec);

    // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
    final byte[] utf8 = textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF8");

    // Encrypt
    final byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(utf8);

    // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
    return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
}
```

Any suggestions, ideas will help me to figure out what's going on here.

Also this is produce different results:

```
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream((pathOfJKSfile)), password.toCharArray());
    Key key = keyStore.getKey(keyName, keyPass.toCharArray());
    byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256");
    final AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);

    final Cipher cipherEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipherEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, paramSpec);

    final byte[] enc = cipherEncrypt.doFinal(messageBytes);
    System.out.println( new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc));
```

And i know that cipher.init() using "JceSecurity.RANDOM" for pruducing different results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Both algorithms, `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256` and `PBEWithMD5AndDES`, first generate an encryption key by processing a password, a salt and an iteration count (using `HmacSHA512` and `MD5`, respectively) and then encrypt the plain text (with `AES-256` and `DES`, respectively) using this key and the [`CBC`-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)). When the `Cipher`-instance is initialized, a pseudo-random [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_(IV)) (IV) is generated that is required for the `CBC`- mode.
- In the context of `PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256`, the IV is generated *using the `SecureRandom` implementation of the highest-priority installed provider*, at least for the [`Cipher#init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init(int,java.security.Key,java.security.AlgorithmParameters))-method used in the code (note that there are several overloads of the `Cipher#init()`-method and that a `SecureRandom`-instance can also be passed explicitly). I.e. with each `Cipher`-initialization a **new** (random) IV is generated and therefore the encrypted text is always different, even for an identical plain text. For this reason, the encrypted text in your examples changes in this context.
- In the context of `PBEWithMD5AndDES`, the IV is **only** determined by the password, the salt, the iteration count (and of course the `MD5`-hash-algorithm itself). Therefore, the IV and the encrypted text do not change in case of repetition (provided that password, salt, iteration count etc. are the same). For this reason, the encrypted text in your example does not change in this context.
- The generation of a new, random IV during the Cipher-initalization makes sense with regard to the following requirements for the IV: For security reasons, an IV in `CBC`-mode (btw this also applies to other modes) [may only be used once under the same key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_(IV)). In addition the IV must be unpredictable.
- `PBEWithMD5AndDES` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143361/what-is-pbewithmd5anddes).

**EDIT:**

- The use of an IV is standard nowadays (for security reasons). A lot of information can be found on the Internet on this topic e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). In the following I will only describe a few basic things.
- The IV used for encryption must be stored in some way because it is required for decryption. The IV does not have to be kept secret, so that it is usually concatenated with the encrypted data (e.g. before the encrypted data) and stored together with them. During decryption, both parts can be separated because the length of the IV is known (16 Byte for AES). E.g for the concatenation in the encryption-method something like the following is used (let `iv` and `enc` be the byte-arrays with the IV and the encrypted data, respectively):

  ```
  byte[] result = new byte[enc.length + iv.length];
  System.arraycopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.length);
  System.arraycopy(enc, 0, result, iv.length, enc.length);
  ```

  and in the decryption-method the corresponding counterpart (having in mind that the length of an IV in AES is 16 Byte).
- In the encryption-method the IV can be determined with `Cipher#getIV()` (this must of course happen after calling `Cipher#init()`).
- In the decryption-method you have to pass the IV to the `PBEParameterSpec`-ctor (e.g. let `iv` be the byte-array with the IV):

  ```
  IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv); 
  AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount, ivSpec);
  ```
- The generation of an IV can also take place outside the `Cipher`-class, see e.g. [Generating random IV for AES in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267435/generating-random-iv-for-aes-in-java). Then you have to pass that IV in the encryption-method in the same way as above described for the decryption-method.
- Note, in connection with an IV some points have to be considered e.g. using a mode without an IV (e.g. ECB), using an IV consisting exclusively of `0`-values, using a predictable IV or using an IV more than once under the same key etc. drastically reduces security in general, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)!

Comment: Thank you @Topaco. I know PBEWithMD5AndDES deprecated. If every encryption generates different results how can i decrypt password for further usage. For ex, properties file contains encrypted password and i will use it for many times in my app.

Comment: I have extended my answer, see the edit-section of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Topaco. I solved my issues with your suggestions. Have a good day.